# Error: invalid_client when following five minute quick start for PHP

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am trying the "Five minute quick start" ( https://developers.google.com/drive/ ) and have followed all instructions up to step 4 "Run the sample".  (I have changed the client ID and secret in the sample php code - I've followed the instrictions in text and watched the video to be sure I didn't miss anything).  When I run the script from command line, I am indeed provided with a link to follow - such as this:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&client_id=938259907386.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force

But when I point my browser there (logged into Google console) I consistently get an error:

Error: invalid_client ... and the details are:

```
response_type=code
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
redirect_uri=http://localhost
access_type=offline
approval_prompt=force
client_id=938259907386.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

I've tried deleting the client ID and re-creating, but I keep running into the same error.  Any suggestions on what could be going wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: It's strange, if I simply replace the client ID in this URl with one of my test client ID it works correctly. Could you take a screenshot of your client ID credentials in the APIs Console and upload it online please? (just make sure your hide the secret... or simply delete that credentials afterwards) PS: you are not the forst one to repport this so something must be wrong somewhere...

Comment: Not sure how to upload screenshot - but here's a copy/paste from Console:Client ID for installed applications
Client ID:  
938259907386.apps.googleusercontent.com
Client secret:  
***
Redirect URIs:  urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob http://localhost

Comment: Issue on our side! We'll keep you updated!

Comment: Just wanted to let you know we're aware of the issue and working to resolve it.

Comment: Not working for me yet, though the interaction has changed. Now I get an allow/deny page and I allow. It then redirects me with a URL like this: http://localhost/?code=4/3SNAio7mbjFq0blSwft44MdpZTK2.QrIzxXzGj8McaDn_6y0ZQNi2gJfoeQI ... and when I try to use parts of the URL in answer to the prompt "Please enter the auth code:", I get fatal errors [Google_authException - Google_OAuth2.php:113].